# Angular translate onetime bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

Hi all I'm using Angular translate and have setup a number of bindings on my pages. Syntax is like the below example

```
{{::'GEN_NAME' | translate}}
```

All works fine but upon page refresh I seem to loose the translation and just the translation id is returned so in the code about I would just get

```
GEN_NAME
```

This seems to happen only in directives though and the onetime binding is okay on pages. We have a lot of our pages made up of directives.

The language file en.json is set in an angular config setup piece of code on the module, eg:

```
(function() {

var core = angular.module('app.core');


core.config(['$translateProvider', 'languageServiceProvider', function    ($translateProvider, languageServiceProvider) {

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/languages/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    languageServiceProvider.$get().setStartLanguage();
}]);
```

})();

languageServiceProvider is just a service that sets the language as in

```
$translate.preferredLanguage(etCurrentLanguage.currentLanguage.code);
```